# How can I change the color of a cell based on the contents of it compared to all other cells in the page

Tags: excel

I have 2 lists of resources , lets say in column E1 through E5 I have listed Tool 1 through Tool 5 ,  Then in  F1 through F5 I have Technician 1 through Technician 5.

Then in columns A through D I have a list of jobs to which these tools and techs can be sent.
I would like the colors of the cells where the tools and techs are listed to change when their names are typed anywhere else in the page.

How can be easiest achieved?

Comment: Which Application are you using?

Comment: Benjamin Schwalb,  I am using Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

Choose the cell(s) you want the format applied to, go to "Conditional Format" - "New rule" - pick the last one and type this: `=$A$1="Name"`

This is probably not the right solution, and it seems as you can´t use multiple values to compare to, but it might be something to start with.